# time domain reflectometry interpretation of a simple circuit

Tags: tdr

I have constructed the following circuit in HSPICE,and it gives me the following waveform

I know that we have the first wave hit node 3 then it goes back and again to node 3.

But how we construct the impedance to time domain plot from this voltage to time plot?

Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: *I know that we have the first wave hit node 3 then it goes back and again to node 3* - that isn't true if the t-line is 50 ohm; there won't be a reflection at the source. *But how we construct the impedance to time domain plot from this voltage to time plot?* - I'm unsure what you are wanting to do here.

Comment: Hello Andy, i Want to know how using TDR (voltage to time plot)we find the source of the INSERTION loss problem if it arives.(exact location of problemtaic spot)

Comment: Maybe [this will help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/539270/tdr-unexpected-results/539273#539273). Maybe [this will help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/538062/time-domain-reflectometer-looking-for-faults/538076#538076). I'm offering these QAs because I'm struggling to understand what it is you really want to know @ron

Comment: Hello Andy ,Th ecapacitor causes this small dip, i cant see why?
could you plaese help me with the reflection logic here?
Thanks.